# Is there some way to share objects among multiple tomcat on a load-balanced cluster?

Tags: java, tomcat, hazelcast

I have two tomcat instances running on a load-balanced cluster. I also have an application that runs on these two instances, and I have two doubts:

1. When an object changes his state in an instance, does it change on the other, that is, keeping the same state (of this specific object) on both instances?
2. If the answer is no, then how can I share the keep the same object state on both instances without using the database?

Comment: By default, no changes to objects in memory are going to be shared across different servers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tomcat 6 cluster with shared objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188474/tomcat-6-cluster-with-shared-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is ok to add some dependencies to the project, then maybe you should consider using [Hazelcast](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#preface). It is quite easy to configure a cluster, and it offers an [IAtomicReference](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#iatomicreference), that seems to be a good fit for your needs.

To spin up a node in a Hazelcast cluster in code, you just run:

```
HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
```

This creates an instance by reading some config xml or by using default settings, if they are not defined. To create and assign an atomic reference that will store and distribute your object, you can call something like:

```
IAtomicReference<Foo> ref = instance.getAtomicReference("terefere");
if(ref.isNull()){
    ref.set(new Foo());
}
```

You can then change the state of the referenced object by applying functions to it, as in:

```
ref.apply(foo -> foo.setBar(true));
```

Comment: Thanks, man.. I'll read its docs.. Only one possible naive question: does Hazelcast consider instances in different computers with differents IP, right?

Comment: Yes, Hazelcast automatically searches nodes over the network.

Comment: For those starting in HazelCast, you can watch the videos here: http://hazelcast.org/getting-started/